# This palindrome code returns error only while submitting in leetcode, its working in my local for same testcase

Tags: javascript

This code return "false" for test input "1" only when I submit in leet code. It's working when I do it in my local or leet code editor for the same input

```
var temp = 0;
var rev = 0;
var palindromeCheck = function (org) {

    temp = org % 10;
    rev = rev * 10 + temp;
    org = parseInt(org / 10);
    if (org > 0) {
        palindromeCheck(org);
    }

    return rev;
};

var isPalindrome = function (x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(x > 0) {
        var value = palindromeCheck(x);
        if (value === x) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

your **palindromeCheck()** function return a `number`. The problem comes from this part, where you strictly compare a `number` and a `string`:

```
if (value === x) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

try to do :

```
if (value == x) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

or

```
return (value == x);
```

else you can just use **parseInt()** function.

Comment: x is also a number and value is also a number so I strictly compared both, as I mentioned for the same test cases it is successful in both my local and leetcode editor.  Anyway I will give it a try